# setPrimaryItem() on FragmentPagerAdapter isn't called after going back to activity from background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

When I launched my app, at the first time `setPrimaryItem()` was called, I added a new fragment to the host activity. This fragment got the data set from the current fragment on viewpager. I added it inside `setPrimaryItem()` because I wanted to make sure the addition fragment would be created after creating viewpager fragments.

```
 @Override
            public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                if (latestFragment == null) {
                    latestFragment = (ViewPagerFragment) object;
                    addAdditionFragment();
                }

                    latestFragment = (ViewPagerFragment) object;
                super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
            }
```

This is what happened when I run my app:

```
HostActivity.setPrimaryItem();
ViewPagerFragment.onAttach();
ViewPagerFragment.onCreate();
ViewPagerFragment.onCreateView();
ViewPagerFragment.onActivityCreated();
ViewPagerFragment.onStart();
ViewPagerFragment.onResume();
AdditionFragment.onAttach();
AdditionFragment.onCreate();
AdditionFragment.onCreateView();
AdditionFragment.onActivityCreated();
AdditionFragment.onStart();
AdditionFragment.onResume();
```

After I minimized my app to the background and opened some other apps. I went back to the app, HostActivity and fragments were created again. I didn't see the activity as well as my fragments were destroyed since I minimized my app, only `onStopped()` was called.

This is what happened:

```
ViewPagerFragment.onAttach();
ViewPagerFragment.onCreate();
AdditionFragment.onAttach();
AdditionFragment.onCreate();
ViewPagerFragment.onCreateView();
ViewPagerFragment.onActivityCreated();
AdditionFragment.onCreateView();
AdditionFragment.onActivityCreated();
ViewPagerFragment.onStart();
ViewPagerFragment.onResume();
AdditionFragment.onStart();
AdditionFragment.onResume();
```

As you can see, AdditionFragment was created at the beginning even though `setPrimaryItem()` was not called. The data AdditionFragment tried to get from a ViewPager fragment was null since latestFragment was null.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states) buddy. Also, other than this, you could still use on resume and on pause if you like those more.